# get rid of horizontal scrollbar on jquery cycle slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slider, scrollbar, jquery-cycle

I'm looking to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar that appears when the browser window is smaller than 1900px
http://focalpoint.wpconsult.net/

the images are 1900px, but can be cut off when the browser is smaller, as long as the slideshow stays centered and the images don't scale, so fixed width.

I set overflow hidden on the container, but that doesn't help. on the other pages, the header has a normal background image with the same width, but the overflow hidden works fine, no scrollbar.

lots of solutions suggest to add overflow hidden on the body element, but that would make it impossible to scroll left and right to read the content on a minimized browser window. I just want the slideshow area to be cut off
thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#header-bg-img` `div` element has a width of `1900px` and that is causing the scrolling

I believe what you need is to add `min-width:980px;` and `overflow:hidden` on the `#wrap` element

The `min-width` will allow the element to expand to greater widths, but if it gets smaller than 980 (*what the rest of the page is designed for*) it will allow scrolling..

Comment: My browser was slow to show me that Gaby had already answered with the same info.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:hidden` to your `#wrap` style will remove the horizontal scrollbar.